# Synchronization issues with RealTimeScheduler

Tags: omnet++, inet

I want to implement network simulation (OMNeT++ as a network emulator receives the position information passed in the gazebo of the physical simulator), so I use `ExtLowerEthernetInterface`, and the use of this port requires the `RealTimescheduler` scheduling class. Although the role of `RealTimescheduler` is to simulate the time as close as possible to the time in the real world. Makes the simulation appear to be running in real time, but this still has some lag.
How to erase or reduce this difference?

[image]
[image]

```
[General]
network = AODVNetwork
scheduler-class = "inet::RealTimeScheduler"
#realtimescheduler-scaling = 120
**.fcsMode = "computed"
**.crcMode = "computed"

*.numHosts = 20
num-rngs = 3
**.mobility.rng-0 = 1   #随机生成mobility模块的初始位置或速度
**.wlan[*].mac.rng-0 = 2  #生成所有WLAN接口的MAC地址。

# channel physical parameters
**.wlan[*].typename = "AckingWirelessInterface"
**.wlan[*].bitrate = 2Mbps
**.wlan[*].mac.headerLength = 23B
**.wlan[*].radio.typename = "UnitDiskRadio"
**.wlan[*].radio.transmitter.headerLength = 96b
**.wlan[*].radio.transmitter.communicationRange = 250m
**.wlan[*].radio.transmitter.interferenceRange = 0m
**.wlan[*].radio.transmitter.detectionRange = 0m
**.wlan[*].radio.receiver.ignoreInterference = true


*.host[19].numEthInterfaces = 1
*.host[19].eth[0].typename = "ExtLowerEthernetInterface"
*.host[19].eth[0].device = "veth0"

# mobility
**.host[*].mobility.typename = "StationaryMobility"
**.mobility.constraintAreaMinZ = 0m
**.mobility.constraintAreaMaxZ = 0m
**.mobility.constraintAreaMinX = 0m
**.mobility.constraintAreaMinY = 0m
**.mobility.constraintAreaMaxX = 600m
**.mobility.constraintAreaMaxY = 600m



# ping app (host[0] pinged by others)
*.host[0].numApps = 2
*.host[0].app[0].typename = "PingApp"
*.host[0].app[0].startTime = uniform(1s,5s)
*.host[0].app[0].printPing = true
*.host[0].app[1].typename = "UdpSink"
*.host[0].app[1].localPort = 8000


*.host[19].numApps=1
*.host[19].app[0].typename = "UdpEchoApp"
*.host[19].app[0].localPort = 8080


# nic settings
**.wlan[*].bitrate = 2Mbps

# lifecycle
**.hasStatus = true

*.host[*].wlan[*].radio.transmitter.communicationRange = 250m
#*.host[0].wlan[0].radio.displayCommunicationRange = true
#*.host[16].wlan[0].radio.displayCommunicationRange = true
#*.host[1].wlan[0].radio.displayCommunicationRange = true
#*.host[19].wlan[0].radio.displayCommunicationRange = true
*.host[0].app[0].destAddr = "host[1](ipv4)"
```

Comment: Could you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76380352/edit) the question and provide [mcve] of your problem?

Comment: Sorry, I can't provide it but you can add this code scheduler-class = "inet::RealTimeScheduler" in the AODV example provided by the INET library. You will notice the difference. Because I feel this is the root problem of RealTimeScheduler class

Comment: Could you at least describe what version of INET, OMNeT++, OS you use and how to reproduce your problem? Moreover, could you describe your testbed - ExtLowerEthernetInterface requires access to emulated port. It's difficult to help you without that information.

Comment: My INET version is 4.4.0, OMNeT++ version is 6.0.1, and my operating system is Ubuntu20.04. My ini code has been re-edited into the question. Thank you for your help, hope to get your answer

Comment: And also please share errors and logs in text form instead of posting a screenshot.